# Django annotate on property field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django REST Framework`

I have a model like below.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AmountGiven(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text='Amount given to the contact')

    @property
    def total_payable(self):
        return self.amount

    @property
    def amount_due(self):
        returned_amount = 0
        for returned in self.amountreturned_set.all():
            returned_amount += returned.amount

        return self.total_payable - returned_amount

class AmountReturned(models.Model):
    amount_given = models.ForeignKey(AmountGiven, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloadField()
```

I have to get the top 10 contacts of the `amount given` and `due` respectively.

In my view, I'm filtering data like

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
def top_ten(request):
    filter_type = request.query_params.get('type', None)

    if filter_type == 'due':
        # query for due type

    elif filter_type == 'given':
        qs = Contact.objects.filter(
            user=request.user
        ).values('id').annotate(
            amount_given=Sum('amountgiven__amount')
        ).order_by(
            '-amount_given'
        )[:10]

        graph_data = []
        for q in qs:
            d = {}
            contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=q['id'])

            d['contact'] = contact.full_name if contact else 'Unknown'
            d['value'] = q['amount_given']
            graph_data.append(d)

        return Response(graph_data)

    else:
        raise NotFound('No data found for given filter type')
```

the `type` query can be **due** or **given**.

**The code for `given` type is working fine as all fields are in the database. But how can I filter based on the virtual field for `due` type?**

What I have to do is to `annotate` **Sum** of `amount_due` property group by `contact`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot filter based on `@property`.

As far as I understand your problem correctly you can aggregate sum of related `AmountGiven` and sum of `AmountReturned`, then calculate `due` field which keep result of subtracting  letter and former.

The query:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Contact.objects.filter(  
    amountgiven__amount__gt=0
).annotate(
    due=Sum('amountgiven__amount') - Coalesce(Sum('amountgiven__amountreturned__amount'), Value(0))
).order_by('-due').values_list('due', 'id')
```

will return:

`<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'due': 2500.0}, {'id': 1, 'due': 2450.0}, {'id': 2, 'due': 1500.0}]>`

However with this solution you cannot distinct between many `AmountGiven` across one `Contact`. You get big picture like results.

If you want split *due* value per `AmountGiven` instance the just annotate like so:

```
AmountGiven.objects.annotate(
    due=Sum('amount') - Coalesce(Sum('amountreturned__amount'), Value(0))
).order_by('-due').values_list('due', 'contact__id', 'id')
```

which returns

```
<QuerySet [
   {'contact__id': 3, 'id': 3, 'due': 2500.0},
   {'contact__id': 1, 'id': 1, 'due': 1750.0},
   {'contact__id': 2, 'id': 2, 'due': 1500.0},
   {'contact__id': 1, 'id': 4, 'due': 350.0},
   {'contact__id': 1, 'id': 5, 'due': 350.0}
]>
```

**References**

1. [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)